# Can you help me to add button in the table cell on click of a button

Tags: angular

I want to add a button in the table cell when i click a button to add a new row in the table in angular. I am able to add a new row but not able to get a button in the cell with the row creation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pleasse try to share a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of what you have tried. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide more details. Please take a look at [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I created a minimum Stackblitz example for you to look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpjesj

Here is my app.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  tablerows = [{
    name: "rowobject"
  }, {
    name: "rowobject"
  }];

  addRow() {
    this.tablerows.push({name: "rowobject"});
  }
}
```

and here is my app.html file

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of tablerows">
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <button (click)="addRow()">add</button>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure that this is an answer to the question.

Comment: I have created another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjziwd) from yours but still I am not sure what it should look like.

Comment: Thank you JosefKatič..your code served the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor (private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

In addRow function, Please add following code

```
 this.cdref.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Why do you think this will solve the problem? Also please add some more description to your answer.